# Free Pascal, trouble with nested ifs and elses

Tags: if-statement, nested, pascal

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? It is supposed to solve quadratic equations:

```
program quadraticeq;
uses crt;
var
    a,b,c,x1,x2,R1,I1,R2,I2,D: integer;
    p:1..4;
begin
    writeln (output, 'Enter a,b i c:');   {ax^2 + bx + c = 0}
    readln (a,b,c);

    D:=sqr(b)-4*a*c;  {discriminant}

    if a=0 then
        p:=1
    else  
        if D=0 then begin
            p:=2;
            x1:=(-b)/(2*a);
            end
        else
            if D>0 then begin
                p:=3;
                x1:=(-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a);
                x2:=(-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a);
            end
            else begin
                p:=4;
                R1:=(-b)/(2*a);
                I1:=sqrt(-D)/(2*a);
                R2:=-R1;
                I2:=-I1;
        end;

    case p of
    1:  writeln (output, 'Wrong entry! Quantificator a mustnt be zero!');
    2:  writeln (output, 'Double root of the equation is: x1=x2=',x1);
    3:  writeln (output, 'Roots of the equation are x1=',x1,'and x2=',x2,'.');
    4:  writeln (output, 'Complex roots of the equation are x1=',R1,'+i',I1,' and x2=',R2,'+i',I2,'.');
    end;
end.
```

Comment: And? What is it doing that is different from what you want? Are you expecting someone to compile it, run it, test it (based on spec consisting of "solve quadratic equations"), all so you don't have to put any effort into your question?

Comment: By formatting it properly you can see there are some missing `end`.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code under FreePascal, I get:

```
Compiling main.pas                                                               
main.pas(17,21) Error: Incompatible types: got "Double" expected "SmallInt"      
main.pas(22,33) Error: Incompatible types: got "Extended" expected "SmallInt"    
main.pas(23,33) Error: Incompatible types: got "Extended" expected "SmallInt"    
main.pas(27,25) Error: Incompatible types: got "Double" expected "SmallInt"      
main.pas(28,29) Error: Incompatible types: got "Extended" expected "SmallInt"    
main.pas(40) Fatal: There were 5 errors compiling module, stopping               
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

so it looks like a conflict between integer and floating point types. When I switch all variables other than `p` to be of type `real`:

```
var
    a,b,c,x1,x2,R1,I1,R2,I2,D: real;
    p:1..4;
```

then it compiles fine.

And, when executing that with known values:

```
   (x + 1)(x - 3) = 0
=>   x^2 -2x -3   = 0
```

I see:

```
Enter a, b, c:                                                                  
1 -2 -3                                                                          
Roots of the equation are x = 3.00000 or -1.00000.
```

That was done with some slight modifications to the program to make the output more readable but the bulk of the code (specifically the calculations) was left untouched.